# Typescript/Lodash group by -- Trying to group values of a key of an array with their quantity

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, underscore.js, lodash

Code:

```
    this.countSmth = _(data).groupBy('DeliveryStatus').values().map(
      (group) => ({ ...group[0], qty: group.length })
    ), console.log(this.countSmth);
```

I've been experimenting with [this stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbpnqc)z and all works well, giving me the desired result. However in my project the end result looks like [this(link).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb8UB.png)

The HTTP response that I'm using as a source looks like this:

```
{
    {
        "BookingId": "VALUE",
        "OrderNumber": "VALUE",
        "ArrivalTime": "VALUE",
        "DepartureTime": "VALUE",
        "Duration": "VALUE",
        "DeliveryStatus": "Accepted"
    }
]
```

In my Angular project Ive used yarn to add 'lodash' and @types/lodash. I decided to test the same stackblitz text in the same environment and it dosn't seem to work which means I've written it wrong there.

**EDIT: I've created an angular project and imported lodash the same. I replaced the data object that I'm getting with a typed array, here:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbpnqc

Comment: underscore.js or lodash? no angular nor typescript in the question, tags can be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 hours of troubleshooting and some help in another thread + some help from colleagues, I ended up with this function:

```
  let countUniqueValues = (data, key) => {
    return _(data).groupBy(key).values().map(
      (group) => ({ key: group[0][`${key}`], count: group.length })
    ).value()
  }
```

Now, when I update my store, I can call this function to create any kpi I want by passing it the data from the action and the key whose values I want to count.

I don't even have to touch the function at all.

Answer (score 0):

What's the library behind `_` in this stackblitz? In Lodash, you need a [.value()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#prototype-value) at the end to unwrap the value from the chain.

Comment: Hmm, I gave it a go and added it to the end of the lodash chain but it doesn't seem to have made a difference. I've used ` import * as _ from "lodash"` and installed it via Yarn.

Comment: You usually write: `import _ from 'lodash';`. Try to run your code in a console here: https://lodash.com/

Comment: I have created a stackblitz running angular and installed everyhting the same way, typed in a scaled down version of my data array that I'll be working in for simplicity: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qbpnqc